# Require 500 MB memory to read small files in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to read in a small file in spark to run some tests. The file is 4 kB in size. The pyspark job is below:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext

spark_context = SparkContext(appName='cache_test')
sql_context = SQLContext(spark_context)

spark_context.setLogLevel('WARN')

df = (sql_context.read
      .format('com.databricks.spark.csv')
      .load('simple_data.csv')
     )

spark_context.stop()
```

I'm running tests related to the memory footprint, so I would like to configure the amount of memory my executor node will use.

```
spark-submit  --master spark://$(hostname):7077 \
    --total-executor-cores 1  \
    --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.executor.memory=400m \
    --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.3.0  \
    caching_test.py
```

If I allocate less than 500 MB/node, the job will get stuck in a loop, saying it does not have sufficient resources.

```
16/04/28 16:22:20 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

This is repeatable on both my laptop and the desktop machine I use at work. Is this a known feature of spark? Is there some configuration of the server that may cause this behavior?

Thank you in advance!

After a few more tests, it looks like I can get down to 470 MB of allocated memory. What is strange to me is that when I specify 470 MB/node, I look in the application UI, and see the total allocated memory is 511.1 MB (master) + 112.9 MB (worker) = 624 MB. Why is there a discrepancy between the memory I specify, and what I actually get?